# Android - Draw rectangles on a picture resolution independent

Tags: android, resolution

I'm currently working on an Android app for tablets (3.1) where I load a bitmap into my layout, the bitmap is a groundplan and the user can draw rectangles on it (dynamically with canvas), which should represent the different rooms. I save the coordinates of the rooms in a mysql database and everytime the user views this activity i load the cooordinates of the database and draw the rooms on the picture. This works fine for the galaxy tab 10.1 (1280x800). But my question is, how do i manage to show the rectangles at exactly the same location on the picture on any tablet. (no matter what resolution it has)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of drawing rectangles on the canvas, you could draw the rectangles onto a temporary copy of the bitmap, then display that copy instead of the original.

That way, you'd always be working in image coordinates, rather than screen coordinates.